# How to hide Input Format Options and help text under a textarea?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, input-formats

How to hide Input Format Options and help text under a textarea when adding|editing a node?

[image: Screenshot - part to hide selected with red rectangle]

Comment: I think that you can do it if you access the form through `hook_form_alter` however I'm not sure about the details, so I'll not post this as an answer...

Answer (score 27):

You can use hook_form_alter in a custom module to do this.

For instance, in drupal 7:

```
// hook_form_alter function
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // We want this on a specific node type
    if ($form_id == 'NODE_TYPE_node_form') {
        $form['#after_build'][] = 'CUSTOM_MODULE_NODE_TYPE_node_form_after_build';
    }
}

// afterbuild function
function CUSTOM_MODULE_NODE_TYPE_node_form_after_build($form) {
    // We want this on a specific field
    $form['YOUR_FIELD']['und']['0']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: this works but has a side effect: it removes the wysiwyg editor from the text area

Comment: That did the trick for me. I mainly just wanted to clean up the text input.

Comment: its better to mention LANGUAGE_NONE instead of 'und' and also the after_build function should have an role based checking in case other superior roles may view the Text Format box.

Answer (score 27):

For Drupal 7, you can use the [Simplify](http://drupal.org/project/simplify) module. It allows you to hide the Text Format options textarea, as well as other elements on node forms.

Comment: If you look at its source (http://cgit.drupalcode.org/simplify/tree/simplify.module?id=7681b0e), the module use jQuery to hide the text format options. It's a shame because 1: you only want to hide text format and do not need the whole module and 2: javascript becomes a requirement. Why not just hide it with CSS like 
Ionut Adrian Luchian's answer suggests ? It's definetly appropriate and clean.

Comment: simplify didn't work consistently for me. in some cases it worked in others not.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I've used bootstrap theme so maybe because of that.

Comment: Simplify didn't work for me too.

Answer (score 12):

In drupal 6 there is the module [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) which does exactly what you want, there is a 7 dev version but it comes with a warning that it's under heavy development. If you site is still in development then it might be worth giving it a shot.

Comment: Seemed to work well for users that weren't admin, even if you remove the permissions for the admin group, user 1 will still see the options in D7

Comment: Better formats works well for D7, is stable with no serious issues and a Beta 2 release in Jan 2016.

Answer (score 9):

You can actually just kill the format form item.

```
function MY_THEME_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
  $form['comment_body']['#after_build'][] = 'MY_THEME_configure_comment_form';
}

function MY_THEME_configure_comment_form(&$form) {
  unset($form[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format']);
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: +1, the best solution. For future visitors, replace CUSTOM with your active theme's name. This code snippet should go in your template.php script in active theme's folder. And if your site has enabled for multilanguage, replace LANGUAGE_NONE with your language code.

Comment: `CUSTOM` is intended as your custom theme name. You should **NEVER** hard code a language, if you need the active language use `global $language;` to grab it.

Comment: Note: `LANGUAGE_NONE` is a constant with value `und` ... don't use `und`.

Comment: This kills the wysiwyg as well

Answer (score 7):

I think the best solution is, to disallow the access to the text format selection element. If you completely unset it, you will face unwanted side effects as a disappearing WYSIWYG editor. So I propose the following code.

```
function MY_MODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
  $form['comment_body']['#after_build'][] = 'MY_MODULE_hide_text_format';
}


function MY_MODULE_hide_text_format(&$form) {
  $form[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format']['#access'] = false;
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution if you only want to hide it on one particular field.  And the WYSIWYG stays functional.

Answer (score 6):

Use CSS, the easiest way.
[image: Firebug]

```
#body-add-more-wrapper #edit-body-und-0-format {display: none;}
```

[image: The power of CSS and Firebug]

Good luck.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend "although it works" CSS hiding.

Comment: not an answer, a getaway

Comment: Why ? This is a great answer because the question is to hide it, not to remove it. It's not like hiding it would cause a security threat or be bad for SEO... You already define permissions in text format configuration so where is the problem ?

Comment: I would prefer hiding it. +1 vote for you.

Comment: css injector module works wonders. see: http://prntscr.com/cieuvs

Comment: You should not just hide things with CSS, that's the lazy way. It's a bad habit that means bloated DOM. Adjust the output.

Comment: The biggest problem that I see with this method is that it's not accessible.  You should never use `display:none`.

Answer (score 5):

FOR Drupal 7

```
function MODULENAME_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if (isset($type['text_format']['#process'])) {
    foreach ($type['text_format']['#process'] as &$callback) {

      if ($callback === 'filter_process_format') {
        $callback = 'MODULENAME_filter_process_format';
      }
    }
  }
}


function MODULENAME_filter_process_format($element) {
  $element = filter_process_format($element);

  // Change input format to "Filtered HTML" for body fields of NODETYPE_NAME

  if ($element['#bundle'] == 'NODETYPE_NAME' && $element['#field_name'] == 'body') {

    $element['format']['format']['#default_value'] = 'filtered_html';
    $element['format']['format']['#format'] = 'filtered_html';  
    $element['format']['format']['#value']  = 'filtered_html';
    $element['#format'] = 'filtered_html';

  }
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: This is a great technique if you want to hide it on many/all fields.

Answer (score 2):

The another simple way to hide the input format option is removing all other input format from the user profiles you want to hide the option.
For this, go admin->configuration->input formats and remove all the user roles from all other input format except one you want to give by default.

Comment: Only works if you only want to enable plain text. Because you can't disable that one.

Comment: exactly. You can't have "Filtered Text" only. Sorry, but this answer is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

Unchecked "Use the Filtered HTML text format" and "Administer text formats and filters" from people > permissions for anonymous and authorized users so that they couldn't use CKeditor.

Of course you can disable it from CSS by "display: none;" for particular div class (it's .filter-wrapper) and hide all area you have pointed upper but in this case the area is hidden for everyone including superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Install [CSS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector) module (currently there is only a working development version for Drupal 8).

Then go to the administration page of CSS Injector (/admin/config/development/css-injector). Create a new CSS rule with this code (or any code that apply to a class of the formating area text):

```
.filter-guidelines {
    display: none;
}
```

Choose to apply it on *Seven* theme (or any admin theme in use). Save and enjoy!

Comment: Install the css injector 1.x as 2.0 is older. Here's a preview of how it looks: http://prntscr.com/cieuvs -- This module works wonders for css injection vs other modules like CPN (code per node)

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the "Plain text" input format. 
And the RTE is not showing when you use the "Plain Text" input format.

I will be using the CSS option.

Comment: The input format selector is not appearing when the currently logged-in user can use just an input format; that sole input format could be a different one, and the selector would not appear the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
/ hook_form_alter function
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // We want this on a specific node type
    if ($form_id == 'NODE_TYPE_node_form') {
        $form['#after_build'][] = 'CUSTOM_MODULE_NODE_TYPE_node_form_after_build';
    }
}

// afterbuild function
function CUSTOM_MODULE_NODE_TYPE_node_form_after_build($form) {

    // We want to hide input formats and we can do it like following
    $form['body']['und']['0']['format']= '<div style="display:none;">';
    $form['body']['und']['0']['format']= '</div>';   

    return $form;
}
```

Mostly Worked for me with these small changes.

```
$form['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format']['#prefix']<br>
$form['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format']['#suffix']
```

Answer (score 0):

I use both "removing all other input format from the user profiles" and css way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Hide formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_formats) module.

> Hide Formats allows you to collapse the "text format" or "input format" dropdowns to clean up the UI.

Comment: This is a great module but it makes the formats box collapsed, not toally hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [simplify](https://drupal.org/project/simplify) module .

> Simplify allows particular fields to be hidden from the user
>   interface. This helps to de-clutter forms and present a more
>   user-friendly experience to content editors.

Comment: simplify works for other fields, but I couldn't make it work for input formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the formats but still keep them available, try the "[Simplified formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplified_formats)" module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/simplified_formats

It hides the formats details in a little question mark icon next to the format selection dropdown. For many text format filters it really does no good to completely hide the instructions that tell one how to use them. Other filters are more automatic. I think we need a module that allows us to choose what shows up to the end user and what does not.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8. This removes the format area for two fields.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'CUSTOM_MODULE_eform_application_after_build';
}

function CUSTOM_MODULE_eform_application_after_build ($form) {
  unset($form['field_experience']['widget'][0]['format']);
  unset($form['field_miscellaneous']['widget'][0]['format']);
  return ($form);
}
```

Comment: OP specified D7 in the question

Comment: Agreed. However, there is very little online for D8 at this point. I suppose I could make my own question and then answer it. Never tried that.

Comment: that would be the better approach, only because the OP in this case is very specific about the version

Comment: Could you please indicate how to implement it?
How can i find form_id?

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7, you can:

1) Use `hook_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry)` from within a module to alter the theme registry, eq. the theme processors definition.

2) Then alter three theme functions, `theme_filter_tips`, `theme_filter_tips_more_info`, and `theme_filter_guidelines`, and force them to return nothing. As follows:

This is the target function. All of the above theme functions will be redirected to that.

```
function _mymodule_filter_tips($tips, $long = FALSE, $extra = ''){
  return '';
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter
 */
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['filter_tips']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path( 'module', 'mymodule' );
  $theme_registry['filter_tips']['function'] = '_mymodule_filter_tips';
  $theme_registry['filter_guidelines']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path( 'module', 'mymodule' );
  $theme_registry['filter_guidelines']['function'] = '_mymodule_filter_tips';
  $theme_registry['filter_tips_more_info']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path( 'module', 'mymodule' );
  $theme_registry['filter_tips_more_info']['function'] = '_mymodule_filter_tips';
}
```

When you clear your cache, Drupal will seek those filter definitions on the path of your module of choice (see `drupal_get_path`), and return nothing for each filter. Hence, no more text format descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to just make the field "Text (plain, long)".

Done, no code, no modules, no headaches.

If you must allow  *some roles*  to have formatting while others plain text then the closest you can get without extra code or modules is to disable all other formats for that role that just needs plain text.

```
admin/config/content/formats
```

It still leaves the bar and the Help on Text Formats question mark. But eh, it's worth not having extra code.