# How can i add WYSIWYG editor for my custom form textarea?

Tags: wysiwyg

I wrote a custom form module in that I placed one text area:

I've tried in this way:

```
$form['message'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Message'),
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#format' => 'full_html',
  '#default_value' => isset($ntemplates->message) ? $ntemplates->message : '',
  '#maxlength' => 255,
  '#attributes' => array(
  'class' => array('field_info'),
  'rows' => '5',
  'cols' => '200',
  ),
  '#wysiwyg' => TRUE,
);
```

But it doesn't work. How can I integrate WYSIWYG editor in to my text area?

**Note**: I'm using wysiwyg-7.22 and ckeditor-3.6.6.2. In the basic page body section it's working. I wrote one custom module for form. In this I am unable to integrate wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Correct me of I'm wrong, but as far as I remember it was in the documentation of WYSIWYG module. Or maybe you are not using this module? If so, what are you using?

Comment: I'm using wysiwyg-7.22 and ckeditor-3.6.6.2. In the basic page body section it's working. I wrote one custom module for form. In this I am unable to integrate wysiwyg editor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drupal 7 introduces the form element `#type` [`text_format`](https://www.drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#text_format), which is a text-format-enabled version of a [`textarea`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#textarea).

To integrate WYSIWYG into your custom form, just modify the attribute `#type` of form as:

```
'#type' => 'text_format'
```

<sup>*Note:* Tested it with CKEditor v 7.x.</sup>

In case if it doesn't work for you, please check your WYSIWYG configuration.

To hide format options, see: [How to hide Input Format Options and help text under a textarea?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/12220)

Above text field type works in Drupal 7 and 8.

Comment: Please add information which WYSIWYG module your code requires. There are many, at least one universal and few dedicated to single editor libraries.

Comment: Tq, I added '#type' => 'text_format' and I configure ckeditor. It shows one select box with formats(like full_html,plain text) in the bottom of text area. Still issue is not resolved.

Comment: wysiwyg-7.x-2.2 and ckeditor-3.6.6.2

Comment: Just checked the same in my local.. It works fine.. Pls check your wysiwyg config.. Does the editor works well in add content -> body field?

Comment: Try using https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor Module version 7.x-1.16

Comment: yes, editor works with body field in basic page

Comment: Yeah tq... Is it possible to add our custom toolbar plugins in to ckeditor module.

Comment: Yeah @praveen I don't want that text format field @ the bottom of  my text area

Comment: You should check http://margotskapacs.com/2014/05/adding-ckeditor-plugins-manually-in-drupal/ or create a new question if find any problem while creating a plug-in

Comment: Thanks a lot hero, But int the bottom of my ckeditor i got text format select box i don't want that box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19141/discussion-between-user3106407-and-pravin-ajaaz).

Comment: Due to this method, i could get only $form_state['values']['message']['value']. If i upload image using media, then the only option to get image $form_state['values']['message']['safe_value']. But it didn't send safe_value. How to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Note that stored value from field is an array not string. So to set up and use, do:

```
  if (($intro = variable_get('groups_intro', NULL)) == NULL){
    $intro = '';
  }
  $form['groups_intro'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#title' => t('intro'),
    '#default_value'=> $intro['value'],
    '#format' => $intro['format'],
    '#cols' => 200,
    '#rows' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```