# How to hide the text formats help text?

Tags: 8, input-formats

I want to hide the description of the text format under the "Comment" box which says:

- No HTML tags allowed.
- Lines and paragraphs break automatically.

[There are a variety of ways to do this on Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12220/how-to-hide-input-format-options-and-help-text-under-a-textarea), but what about Drupal 8?

Comment: After Drupal core 10 the allowed formats can be set as an option in text fields configuration. See:https://www.drupal.org/node/3318572.

Comment: @dxvargas That's right; we should refresh this question.  Please add that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AFAIK there is currently no core UI to control showing/hiding of those tips.

Th simplify module, one of the D7 choices you link to, has a D8 port that may still help with this.

The [Allowed formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats) module is an incubator for future core improvements in the area of giving sitebuilder's UI control over text format and their help tips.

== UPDATE ==

A patch just committed to that module gives sitebuilders considerable control over help tips, using UI settings on the widgets.

== OLD ==

There are a couple of relevant issue in the issue queue for that module:

[Allow to control if "About text formats" link should be shown or not](https://www.drupal.org/node/2617982)

[Allow to hide text format help text for Text(formatted)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2629618)

The first of those issues contains this code from floretan, which points in the direction you would need to go to hide the help by custom code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function allowed_formats_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  if ($context['widget'] instanceof \Drupal\text\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\TextareaWidget) {
    $element['#after_build'][] = '_allowed_formats_remove_textarea_help';
  }
}

/**
 * #after_build callback.
 */
function _allowed_formats_remove_textarea_help($form_element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if (isset($form_element['format'])) {
    // All this stuff is needed to hide the help text.
    unset($form_element['format']['guidelines']);
    unset($form_element['format']['help']);
    unset($form_element['format']['#type']);
    unset($form_element['format']['#theme_wrappers']);
  }

  return $form_element;
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately removes this the tips and guidelines etc. on all admin pages too ;( To use this only on node edit pages you can check this with `if ('entity.node.edit_form' === \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() && $context…`. And you should thinking about `TextareaWithSummaryWidget` as other possible widget type.

Comment: The second portion of the code helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

This work for me in drupal 8, You have to change the field machine name

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
    $form['field_short_description']['widget']['#after_build'][] = '_allowed_formats_remove_textarea_help';
}



function _allowed_formats_remove_textarea_help($form_element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  if (isset($form_element[0]['format'])) {
    // All this stuff is needed to hide the help text.
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['guidelines']);
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['help']);
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['#type']);
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['#theme_wrappers']);
    $form_element[0]['format']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }

  return $form_element;
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as a correct answer for Drupal 8

Comment: Somehow my $form_element does not have the same values as above, so nothing to disable :-(

Answer (score 3):

As simple and general solution (for all fields)  is to install a contributed theme outside core and use that as a administration theme and simply do something like

.filter-guidelines-item .tips  {
    display:none;
}

Or patch one of the themes inside core and make a note to repatch when you do an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering how to do this in Form API, so when you are creating form elements in a Form class instead of altering form elements afterwards:

Your form element:

```
$form['my_field'] = [
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#title' => 'My Title',
  '#allowed_formats' => ['basic_html'],
  '#after_build' => [[get_class($this), 'hideTextFormatHelpText'],],
];
```

Add this function to your class:

```
  public static function hideTextFormatHelpText(array $element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if (isset($element['format']['help'])) {
      $element['format']['help']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
    if (isset($element['format']['guidelines'])) {
      $element['format']['guidelines']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
    if (isset($element['format']['#attributes']['class'])) {
      unset($element['format']['#attributes']['class']);
    }
    return $element;
  }
```

I specifically also removed the classes because you will otherwise see some padding and a border around something empty that you probably don't want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do this. Filter tips are displayed within a block so you can go to appearance/settings and than go to theme customize css.

Add following:

.filter-wrapper {
    display: none;
}

You can also add.

.description {
    display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

After Drupal core 10 the allowed formats can be set as an option in text fields configuration.

See: https://www.drupal.org/node/3318572.