# How to hide the 'Format Options' / 'Help Text' Guideliness from the bottom of comments textarea?

Tags: theming, 8, comments, wysiwyg, input-formats

How can I remove or hide **Format Options / Guideliness** under the comments textarea in my theme?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a code-less way to do this in your theme. Adding a simple style rule to your theme's CSS can hide this element from display:

```
#edit-comment-body-wrapper .filter-wrapper { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 4):

The best is to add to your CSS file

```
.filter-wrapper
{
display: none;
}
```

There you go, disappeared!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this https://www.drupal.org/node/2599958 most likely won't get commited in any shape or form so you have to a) deny access to the route(if you want to) and add process handler for text_format via hook_element_info_alter.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  // Add process handler for text format so that we can remove
  // formatting tips.
  $types['text_format']['#process'][] = 'MODULENAME_process_text_format_element';
}

/**
 * Text input element process handler that will remove
 * the formatting tips.
 */
function MODULENAME_process_text_format_element(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
  $element['format']['guidelines']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $element['format']['help']['#access'] = FALSE;
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Better formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats) module. It allows you to hide the format options and tips link per user roles and fields.

Answer (score 2):

This is Another solution that i found in: 
[How to hide Input Format Options and help text under a textarea?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12220/how-to-hide-input-format-options-and-help-text-under-a-textarea)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#after_build'][] ='CUSTOM_MODULE_eform_application_after_build';
}

function CUSTOM_MODULE_eform_application_after_build ($form) {
    unset($form['field_experience']['widget'][0]['format']);
    unset($form['field_miscellaneous']['widget'][0]['format']);
    return ($form);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the method that I use:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Here we only delete the format if the user is anonymous,
  // you can eliminate the if() for all the users.
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    $form['field_description']['widget']['#after_build'][] = '_mymodule_allowed_formats_remove_textarea_help';
  }
}

/**
 * Remove the textarea help message.
 *
 * @param array $form_element
 *   The form element.
 * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
 *   The form state.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Images URL Array.
 */
function _mymodule_allowed_formats_remove_textarea_help(array $form_element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if (isset($form_element[0]['format'])) {
    // All this stuff is needed to hide the help text.
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['guidelines']);
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['help']);
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['#type']);
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['#theme_wrappers']);
    $form_element[0]['format']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }

  return $form_element;
}
```